# JButton keeps adding new instance of JFrame

Tags: java

I am having an issue getting my fullscreen/windowed function to work. Currently my main menu works including the fullscreen/windowed functions. However in my game class it will not work correctly, when going to windowed mode more than once it will create a new instance of the JFrame. I have tried the same code that is in my menu class but it is not working like the main menu does. The problem lies within the game class under WindowButtonHandler and FullButtonHandler. I have ran out of ideas on what could possibly be wrong. Here is all the code for all the classes I have, a total of 4. If you want to reproduce the problem click on "Start game..." press "P" on keyboard and click on "Windowed mode..." and then "Fullscreen..." and Alt+tab on windows to view the open windows. Program is runnable through the menu function

Game(one that causes the issue)

```
/**
 * Write a description of class game here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class game extends JPanel
{
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
private WindowButtonHandler wbHandler;
private FullButtonHandler fbHandler;

public int I = 0;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");

public static KeyListener listen;

public game()
{
    initGame();
    sound.music("music/background.wav");
}

public void initGame ()
{
    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/char.gif");


    listen = new KeyListener()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton window = new JButton("Windowed mode...");
        JButton full = new JButton("FullScreen...");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit...");
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

            fbHandler = new FullButtonHandler();
            full.addActionListener(fbHandler);

            wbHandler = new WindowButtonHandler();
            window.addActionListener(wbHandler);

            exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                int i = 1;
                while(i != 2)
                {

                    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    //exit.setVisible(true);
                    panel.add(full);
                    panel.add(window);
                    panel.add(exit);
                    panel.setOpaque(false);
                    add(panel);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    //sound.stop();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                //sound.music("music/background.wav");
                remove(panel);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
        }
    };
    repaint();
    revalidate();

    background.setIcon(image);
    //menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
    //menu.frame.requestFocus();
    //menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    //frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    add(background);
    //setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

public void pause()
{


    System.out.println("test");
}

public class WindowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();
        //FullButtonHandler.frame.dispose();
        //menu.frame.setContentPane(menu.background);

        if(I == 0)
        {
            menu.frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            menu.frame.add(new game());


            menu.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(true);
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            ++I;
        }     
        I = 0;
    }
}

public class FullButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();


        //frame.setContentPane(menu.background);
        if(I == 0)
        {
            menu.frame.add(new game());

            menu.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(true);
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            ++I;
        }          
        I = 0;
    }
}

public void closeWindow(String Frame)
{
    if(frame.equals("frame1"))
    {
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
    if(frame1.equals("frame"))
    {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Menu

```
/**
 * Write a description of class main here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class menu
{
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

JButton start, exit, option;

JPanel panel, pane;
public static JFrame frame;
JLabel background;

Random rand = new Random();

int Background = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
private StartButtonHandler sbHandler;
private OptionButtonHandler obHandler;
private BackButtonHandler bbHandler;
private WindowButtonHandler wbHandler;
private FullButtonHandler fbHandler;
public menu()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    sound.music("music/theme.wav");

    generate.image(Background);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(generate.getImage()));

    start = new JButton("Start game...");
    option = new JButton("Options...");
    exit = new JButton("Exit game...");

    background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(image);
    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    panel.setOpaque(false);

    sbHandler = new StartButtonHandler();
    obHandler = new OptionButtonHandler();
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

    start.addActionListener(sbHandler);
    option.addActionListener(obHandler);
    exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));

    panel.add(option);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));

    frame.setContentPane(background);
    panel.add(exit);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public class StartButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.remove(panel);

        //game.game();
        sound.stop();

        frame.add(new game());
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.addKeyListener(game.listen);
    }
}

public class OptionButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        generate.image(Background);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(generate.getImage()));

         background = new JLabel();
         background.setIcon(image);
         background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton back = new JButton("Back to menu...");
        JButton window = new JButton("Windowed mode...");
        JButton full = new JButton("FullScreen...");

        bbHandler = new BackButtonHandler();
        back.addActionListener(bbHandler);

        wbHandler = new WindowButtonHandler();
        window.addActionListener(wbHandler);

        fbHandler = new FullButtonHandler();
        full.addActionListener(fbHandler);

        pane.setOpaque(false);
        pane.add(window);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));
        pane.add(full);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));
        pane.add(back);
        //frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class BackButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.remove(pane);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();



        frame.add(panel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class WindowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
        frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

public class FullButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
        frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    menu menu = new menu();
}
}
```

Audio class

```
/**
* Write a description of class music here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class sound
{
static AudioPlayer play = AudioPlayer.player;
static AudioStream stream;
static AudioData data;
static ContinuousAudioDataStream loop;
public static void music(String file)
{

     //loops audio

    try
    {
        stream = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(file)); //loads audio file
        data = stream.getData(); //gets data from the AudioStream
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(data); //loops audio
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    play.start(loop);//plays music
}

public static void stop()
{
    play.stop(loop);
}
}
```

soon to be procedural generation code

```
/**
* Write a description of class random here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class generate
{
public static String images;
public static String image;
public static void image(int number)
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            setImage("images/01.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            setImage("images/02.jpg");
            break;
        case 3:
            setImage("images/03.jpg");
            break;
        case 4:
            setImage("images/04.jpg");
            break;
        case 5:
            setImage("images/05.jpg");
            break;
        case 6:
            setImage("images/06.jpg");
            break;
        case 7:
            setImage("images/07.jpg");
            break;
        case 8:
            setImage("images/08.jpg");
            break;
        case 9:
            setImage("images/09.jpg");
            break;
        case 10:
            setImage("images/10.jpg");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}

public static void setImage(String images)
{
    image = images;
}

public static String getImage()
{
    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Generally I am not a big fan of abandoning a perfectly working library such as swing/AWT, but these days JavaFX seems to be the way to go for the simple games. Perhaps consider porting this to JavaFX? I am hoping this is not school homework, as then I would shudder at how retarded that school's curriculum would be.

Comment: Word of advice..class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: This is for school, we aren't being taught this is all myself. There is better ways to do things but this program came from my brain from what I have already been taught. This is a high school course and in computer science 1 at the very end we learned swift and awt.We were taught better naming conventions, actually had a test over it too, I put random names for experimental code and rename them better after. I will probably switch to JavaFX once the game is done. I also plan to port it to android so I will need to learn and port it to that too.

Comment: There are at least four occurrences of `new JFrame` in your code.  How many windows do you actually want to have?  If you only want one window, make sure your code executes `new JFrame` exactly once.  Also, your `closeWindow` method is comparing strings incorrectly;  `==` is for comparing object references.  Always, always, always use the `equals` method to compare strings (for example, `frame.equals("frame1")`).

Comment: I forgot about that VGR! As for the JFrames I want one but couldn't maximize and set it undecorated without the windowed mode being undecorated. I tried setting setUndecorated to false in the function where it calls to be in windowed mode and was still borderless

Comment: @VGR I have tried switching the == to frame.equals("frame1") and frame1.equals("frame") and I am still having the same issue

Comment: Forget about maximizing.  Focus on one problem at a time.  First, make sure your program creates one and only one JFrame. Then worry about maximizing.

Comment: @VGR I just changed my code to use the JFrame from the menu class using menu.frame I kept all code the same but replaced the frame and frame1 with menu.frame, the fullscreen works fine but windowed mode keep flashing into full screen. The original post will have the updated code I am using, the only thing that changed is the game class in the FullButtonHandler and WindowButtonHandler

Comment: If your problem is solved, please ask a new question;  do not change your existing question to an entirely new issue, as all of our comments will cease to make sense to other readers.